# Minimum of Pairwise-Independent Variables

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, independence

Given $X_{1},\dots, X_{n}$ which are uniform on unit interval $[0,1]$, and pairwise independent, i.e. $X_{i}$ and $X_{j}$ are independent for $1\leq i,j\leq n$. Show that $$\Theta\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\leq \mathbb{E}[\min(X_{1},\dots,X_{n})] \leq \Theta\left(\frac{\log{n}}{n}\right).$$

For the lower bound by Markov's inequality,
$$\Pr(\min(X_{1},\dots,X_{n})\geq a) \leq \frac{\mathbb{E}[\min(X_{1},\dots,X_{n})]}{a}$$
By Union Bound,
$$\Pr(\min(X_{1},\dots,X_{n})\geq a) = \Pr(X_{1}\geq a,\dots,X_{n}\geq a)\geq 1-\sum_{i}\Pr(X_{i}\leq a)=1-n\cdot a.$$
Plugging back in
$$\mathbb{E}[\min(X_{1},\dots,X_{n})]\geq \max_{0\leq a\leq 1}{a(1-na)}=\frac{1}{4n}.$$ For uniform i.i.d. variables we establish that the lower bound is tight.
I don't know how to prove the upper bound.

Comment: Where does $P(A_1 \cap \cdots \cap A_n) \ge 1 - P(A_1 \cup \cdots \cup A_n)$ come from? A counterexample for this is $A_1 = \cdots = A_n$ and $P(A_1) < 1/2$.

Comment: I meant the union of the complement of the sets.

Comment: Are your $X_{ij}$ really uniformly distributed (and pairwise independent) in your example? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_distribution

Comment: Now, I remember that rolling a 7 on two dice is more likely than rolling a 2 :). @ClementC.

Comment: Last line should be $\max_{0 \le a \le 1} (a(1-na)) = \frac{1}{4n}$?

Comment: What about addition mod 2? @ClementC. I think that might work.

Comment: @angryavian yes indeed.

Comment: Where does the problem come from?

Comment: It comes up when talking about this algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flajolet%E2%80%93Martin_algorithm @Zhanxiong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can give an upper bound of $O\left(\frac{\log n}{n}\right)$.

For $t\in(0,1)$ let $N_t$ be the number of samples among $X_1,\dots,X_n$ that are at most $t$. Then $\mathbb EN_t=nt$ and pairwise independence implies that $\operatorname{Var}N_t=nt(1-t)$. Then by the second moment method
$$\mathbb P(\min X_i\leq t)=\mathbb P(N_t>0)\geq\frac{\mathbb E[N_t]^2}{\mathbb E[N_t^2]}=\frac{nt}{nt+(1-t)}.$$
So we have
$$\mathbb E[\min X_i]=\int_0^1\mathbb P(\min X_i>t)\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}t\leq\int_0^1\frac{1-t}{(n-1)t+1}\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}t=\frac{n\log n}{(n-1)^2}-\frac{1}{n-1},$$
establishing the upper bound.

Comment: I didn't know of the second moment method, it seems to work. Do you have an idea for a construction?

Comment: @Ethan I don't know what "the second moment method" exactly is either, but to derive the inequality $P[N_t > 0] \geq (E[N_t])^2/E[N_t^2]$, just notice $E[N_t] = E[N_tI_{\{N_t > 0\}}] \leq \sqrt{E[N_t^2] \times P[N_t > 0]}$, by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.